# President-Elect Succession

Tags: us-constitution

If the Electoral College elects a future President and that person dies before taking office, would the Vice-President elect become President?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Government FAQ](https://www.archives.gov/federal-register/electoral-college/print_friendly.html?page=faq_content.html&title=U.%20S.%20Electoral%20College%3A%20Frequently%20Asked%20Questions#candidatedies) on the Electoral College:

> If a winning Presidential candidate dies or becomes incapacitated between the counting of electoral votes in Congress and the inauguration, the Vice President elect will become President, according to Section 3 of the 20th Amendment.

[Section 3 of the 20th Amendment](https://www.archives.gov/federal-register/electoral-college/provisions.html#20):

> If, at the time fixed for the beginning of the term of the President, the President elect shall have died, the Vice President elect shall become President. [...]

Comment: ....................thank you very much !